# Refresh vuetable-2 component from my parent component

Tags: vue.js, vue-tables-2

I have make my own vuetable-2 component and calling this component every time in component where i want to show list.
I want to reload my vuetable-2 component when ever i perform any action on my parent component.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `refresh()` for vuetable . So there is many way to trigger that from parent . You can call directly that method by setting `ref` or use `watch` in component .